# How to automatically launch bootstrap modal in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to launch a modal in react after a certain number of seconds. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ReactStrap to implement bootstrap to react project

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/

Comment: Glad to hear if it helps you, please accept the answer